# Specifying path of delay loaded dlls

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have a third party library that I am linking against with the visual studio 2013 linker "/delayload" option during the creation of my DLL (a plugin for another third party application).

The problem with this, is that I cannot find a means to specify the path of where the third party DLL can be found (my DLL is to be placed in a plugins directory that the parent application searches, and loads the found plugins). As such the DLL of third party library has to be placed in the directory of the parent application. This is unacceptable.

I know that during deployment deployment of my DLL, I could specify a new directory path in the system environment's path variable. However if possible, I would like to avoid this step.

Is it possible to specify a path of the DLL that is to be delayloaded, without having to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. Using the run-time linking route is less appealing than modifying the path variable because there are far too many functions that need to be loaded!

Comment: See [Understanding the Helper Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds(v=vs.120).aspx) and in particular the `dliNotePreLoadLibrary` [notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0fkfy9y(v=vs.120).aspx) which allows you to `LoadLibrary` from anywhere you choose, then let the delay loader use the `HMODULE` you return.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The kicker is now, that the loaded DLL loads another 4 DLLs, for which I cannot specify the DelayLoad option because I am not linking against any of the functions in these DLLs. Subsequently, I cannot specify the path where these DLLs can be found, which means that they need to be stored in the same directory as the application.. (my original problem).. Is the solution here to change during the "dliNotePreLoadLibrary" notification to change the DLL search path with SetDllDirectory?

Comment: SetDllDirectory (or [AddDllDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513.aspx) in Windows 8+) should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the proper answer would be to use the delay load hooks. You would set the hook and when you get the preload notification for your dll, then you can do `LoadLibrary` with your library's full path.

**MSDN docs:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/understanding-the-helper-function?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170#sample-hook-function

**Full answer from Raymond Chen here:** https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170126-00/?p=95265